# Highcharts Flags are not visible in some cases

Tags: javascript, typescript, highcharts, highcharts-ng, angular2-highcharts

I found a bug in highcharts where a group of Flags are placed on one spot. (http://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/246d13up/2).
The bug already got reported on the [Highchart Gitlab](https://github.com/highcharts/highcharts/issues/10073).
A developer posted a [workaround](http://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/246d13up/). He overrided the "H.seriesTypes.flags.prototype._drawPoints()" function.

I located the function in the [documentation](https://api.highcharts.com/class-reference/Highcharts.Series#drawPoints), but i didn't find a way to override it in typescript.

My attempts to override it didn't bring me to the solution.

```
series: Highcharts.Series = {
    drawPoints: function () {

    }
  };


  points: Highcharts.Point = {
    series: {
      drawPoints: function () {
        return;
      }
    }
  }
```

Comment: Are you trying to use it in Angular? Which wrapper do you use?

Comment: @KarolKołodziej yes i try to use it in angular. In my html file i implemented it like this.
Sry, the code formatting didnt work. Here is a [picture](http://prntscr.com/131id2u).
`  <highcharts-chart
    [Highcharts]="Highcharts"
    [constructorType]="'stockChart'"
    [callbackFunction]="chartCallback"
    [options]="options"
    style="height: 650px; display: block;">
  </highcharts-chart>  ` .

In my typescript file i have the highcharts as a variable.

Comment: [Link](http://prntscr.com/131ijqt)
`  Highcharts: typeof Highcharts = Highcharts;

  chartRef: Highcharts.Chart;
  chartCallback: Highcharts.ChartCallbackFunction = (chart) => {
    this.chartRef = chart;
  }; ` 

I only changed the highchart designs in options up to now.
`    options: Highcharts.Options = { `

Comment: In the demo below I've created a custom component with the wrap. This is one way of how you can make it in Angular. Demo: https://stackblitz.com/edit/highcharts-angular-custom-plugin-ycadmt